# Ugly WPF hotkey

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have some commands that use Ctrl-Win- as hotkeys. However, MenuItem displays these as Ctrl-Windows-, which is quite ugly. How can I modify it so that "Win" is displayed instead of "Windows". Yuck. Help!

[image]

Comment: Please try to avoid Ctrl+Windows shortcuts for your application. The Windows key is meant to be used by Windows and only by Windows. Users won't expect it. Consider Ctrl+Alt+X or Ctrl+Shift+X instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `InputGestureText` property of the `MenuItem`. Just remember to do it **before** the command binding.

**EDIT**
If you do not want to repeat that for each `Menuitem` you may iterate all the `MenuItem`s to change their `InputGestureText` property programmatically. As alternative, if you're using *custom* input bindings, you may derive a class from `KeyGesture` and override `GetDisplayStringForCulture` to do the replacement.

Comment: You mean I have to manually do it for all hotkeys with "Win"?

Comment: YES! There are some alternatives but I guess they're even more tricky. You can iterate all the MenuItem to change their InputGestureText. If you're using _custom_ input bindings you may derive your own KeyGesture class and override GetDisplayStringForCulture to do the stuff.

Comment: Apparently the third argument of new KeyGestures is the display name. I think deriving a new KeyGesture may be what I want to do.

Comment: To use the third argument is like to set the InputGestureText, if you drive a new class you change its behavior and you do not have to specify a display name every time. Anyway I prefer the display name/InputGestureText solution 'cause it's more _local_.